# How to activate GearVR Menu in my own Unity-Apps?

Tags: unity, mobile, virtual-reality, augmented-reality

So in normal GearVr-Apps, which you can download from the marketplace, you can activate the GearVr Menu to control brightness etc. with a long click on the back button. But this does not work for all of my apps which I made with Unity for the GearVr, is there something special I have to import into my project?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the utilities for Unity? [According to the docs](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-ovrinput/#unity-ovrinput-gear-vr), the long click on the back button should **always** show the GearVr Menu. But, if it is not working, there is also a script (OVRPlatformMenu.cs) in the utilities that does that. You can find more info about the script [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-utilities-overview/#unity-scripts-scenes).

Good luck